# Why does the size of files shown in gitlab decrease after we fork the repository

Tags: gitlab

I am new to GitLab, and I am wondering if any data is lost when I forked the repo?

- file size from orginal repo is 2.2 gb:
  [image: file size from orginal repo is 2.2 gb]
- file size after i fork the repo is 1.3gb
  [image: file size after i fork the repo is 1.3gb]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either associated released are counted in the Storage size of a repository (and a fork would not copy those releases).
I don't see that criteria in [Storage limits](http://git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3835) though.

Or the first repository is [using LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) and those are not available in the fork (issue in progress: [271576](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/271576), possibly because of [`git-lfs/git-lfs` issue 3835](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3835)

If not, using [GitLab repository cleanup](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html#repository-cleanup) would help removes internal Git references to upload objects, reducing the size of the first repository.